# Clang tidy, используемый в clion, считает ошибкой функционал, связанные с c++20

Tags: clion, c++20

Clang tidy, используемый в clang, считает ошибкой функционал, связанные с c++20. Как это можно исправить, стандарту год, неужели нет решений?

На этом скрине весь код работает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Напишите на форум Clion. Они, насколько мне известно, доделывают clang инструменты под себя. Возможно ещё не подвезли. Но, в любом случае, clang пока не поддерживает на 100% с++20, так что...

Comment: загуглил за Вас и компанию, которая по хорошему должна отвечать здесь на такие ворпосы для пиара своего продукта (но видимо им это не очень интересно) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/c-20-concepts.html - там "да, мы знаем, да делаем, когда будет - кто его знает"